# Stuck at input emacs gdb debugging C program /* enter doesn't end text input */

Tags: c, gdb

Hello I am novice programmer and I am trying to debug a simple C program, using `getline` (from the K&R book at the beginning) - input ends on newline.

I have a problem with gdb on Emacs. When I debug from the shell the program works normally. When it reaches the input line and asks for input I type my input, press enter and proceed with debugging steps. However when I debug with the command `M-x gdb` (*run with default settings*) the program reaches the input line and asks for input.  I type my input and then cannot proceed debugging: <kbd>RET</kbd> doesn't get me out of the input stage and the program seems to wait for more input.

Update: works fine with M-x gud-gdb

Answer (score 3):

Type your input in the "input/output" window. Not in the "gud" window.

In the layout shown in [GDB User Interface Layout](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GDB-User-Interface-Layout.html) 
it is the one labled "I/O buffer for debugged pgm"

Comment: Just to add a bit more context, you will need to switch to the \*I/O\* buffer to type your input. Then you will need to switch back to the \*gdb\* buffer to continue to execute your gdb commands.